# Flutter Equatable for partially immutable class

Tags: flutter, dart, equality, hashcode

Dart says to [avoid equality on mutable classes](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-custom-equality-for-mutable-classes):

> ### AVOID defining custom equality for mutable classes
>
> When you define `==`, you also have to define `hashCode`. Both of those should take into account the object’s fields. If those fields *change* then that implies the object’s hash code can change.
>
> Most hash-based collections don’t anticipate that—they assume an object’s hash code will be the same forever and may behave unpredictably if that isn’t true.

That's reasonable. But what about classes with an immutable part like an unique ID on which hashcode and equality shall be calculated with and other mutable attributes which shall be ignored. Is that not possible?

Comment: "The code is more what you’d call ‘guidelines’ than actual rules.” – Barbossa, Pirates of the Caribbean. In other words, the effective Dart guide lines is not something you are forced to follow but just good advice. If it makes sense for your use case, nothing prevents you from going in a different direction. But I would personally be confused if `==` and `hashCode` did not check all fields in a class. :)

Comment: totally possible, but some state management solutions may ignore new values emitted as being the same since you don't check the mutable fields for inequality. And this may cause your widgets to not rebuild themselves

Answer (score 0):

To quote section of [Effective Dart: Design](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-custom-equality-for-mutable-classes) that you linked and refer to:

> ### AVOID defining custom equality for mutable classes
>
> When you define `==`, you also have to define `hashCode`. Both of those should take into account the object’s fields. If those fields *change* then that implies the object’s hash code can change.
>
> Most hash-based collections don’t anticipate that—they assume an object’s hash code will be the same forever and may behave unpredictably if that isn’t true.

The only reason given in the guide for avoiding custom equality is to prevent hash-based collections from behaving unpredictably if an object's hash code changes.  This is impossible in the scenario you've given where the hash code cannot change after object construction.  Therefore, it should be safe (if potentially inconsistent) to define `==` and `hashCode` or such an object.